# Is "incredible" a gradable or non-gradable adjective?

Tags: adjectives, gradability

Is *incredible* a gradable or non-gradable adjective?

I noticed many books in Google state its comparative and superlative forms 
*more incredible* and *most incredible*, so according to this view = gradable.

On the other hand, I noticed in two good sites they used *absolutely* before it.
We know *absolutely* = grading adverb is used before non-grading adjectives ( extreme adjective).

So, how can these contradicting views be illustrated or be depended on?

Here is an example

> *It was absolutely an incredible movie*. (not very incredible)

As it is and according to Longman dictionary = extremely good, large, or great SYN unbelievable.

So and according to the meaning above: = non-gradable = something is likely extraordinary or unusual

I don't know why these many grammar books in Google stated its comparative and superlative. You can go to Google and search yourselves. Students can be confused by those authors.

Comment: The literal meaning of _incredible_ is _impossible to believe_. Something is either possible to believe or it isn't, so a comparative is not appropriate. However, the colloquial use of _incredible_ means, as Longman says, extremely good, so it would be OK to use a comparative here.

Comment: Some adjectives are gradeabler than others.

Comment: I don’t think *absolutely* is modifying *incredible* at all in your example.  It’s modifying how strongly you *think* it was an incredible movie.

Comment: OTOH, they might say "It was a *very incredible* movie", which is treating it as gradable.

Comment: 'Incredible' is gradable for me (something like 'amazing'). If the word is gradable then this all works out fine right? Suppose you say 'absolutely pregnant' - that seems fine also, but maybe pleonastic for some. I don't see a problem here that needs fixing, no contradiction at all. What is the contradiction?

Answer (score -1):

Now, I am satisfied that ( incredible) = strong adjective or extreme because its meaning = unbelievable and when something is so described = extraordinary = nothing or no adjective has intense more what described. Therefore,such adjective, no doubt = extreme adjective 
In addition, here it is mentioned ( Grammar Bank)

Intensifiers
Intensifiers With Strong Adjectives
It was absolutely an incredible movie. (not very incredible)
It was exceptionally an amazing experience. (not very amazing)
Some strong intensifiers are: absolutely / exceptionally / really / quite
https://www.grammarbank.com/intensifiers.html